# Unexpected results using info from `mdls` to search via `mdfind`

Tags: terminal, spotlight

I wanted to find what program created a dot file.
I ran `mdls /path/to/file` on the file.

```
john@iMacEth ~ % mdls /Users/john/Library/Application\ Support/.lldb_info_3F4AF17D8C 
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate = 2023-08-14 21:14:13 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate      = 2023-08-14 21:14:13 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode       = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags       = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon     = 0
kMDItemFSInvisible         = 1
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery      = 0
kMDItemFSLabel             = 0
kMDItemFSName              = ".lldb_info_3F4AF17D8C"
kMDItemFSNodeCount         = 181
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID      = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID       = 501
kMDItemFSSize              = 181
kMDItemFSTypeCode          = ""
```

In the past I've been able to find which program created it just looking at the modification date and cross referencing what programs where installed around that time.

I tried to find using

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSCreationDate > $time.iso(2023-08-14 21:14:00) &&  kMDItemFSCreationDate < $time.iso(2023-08-14 21:14:20)'
```

This returned no results... not even the file in question was returned.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: I have answered your question below, but your "real" question might be what is a `.lldb_info` file.

Comment: That is part of it. And having general knowledge and a method of determining what files are, how they were installed and by what program - without having to do a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the behaviour you are seeing with a test on my Mac.  But that is only when I, like you, enter the time without the time zone.

The file creation date/time is `2023-08-14 21:14:13 +0000` (as in your `mdls` output). The Spotlight index is storing date/time as in time zone +00. So you need to specify that time zone in your `mdfind`. Try  this:

`mdfind 'kMDItemFSCreationDate > $time.iso(2023-08-14 21:14:00 +0000) &&  kMDItemFSCreationDate < $time.iso(2023-08-14 21:14:20 +0000)'`

The equivalent works for my test file.